# How to change admin name and logout threshold with powershell win2k12 R2

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, service

I am trying to automate some regular tasks, and I need some help. Does powershell compile like C++ or is a simple batch file like the old .bat

*Is there an online lint/editor for powershell place like jsfiddle?*

Main question: I need help with **automating** some of these **into a powershell script** (both interactive and non-interactive modes) and **looking at if they succeed**

1. Change user/admin name `Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name -like 'admin*'" | Foreach-Object {$_.Rename("Dingbats)")}`
2. [Turn on lockout threshold](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994574.aspx) to 3 attempts and set it to 45 mins

   `PS C:\> Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Identity SS64.com -LockoutDuration 00:40:00 -LockoutObservationWindow 00:20:00 -ComplexityEnabled $true -ReversibleEncryptionEnabled $false -MaxPasswordAge 10.00:00:00`

another example

```
 # set lockout threshold value
 # how do I **change $mydomain to my server name** or local server automatically??
 PS C:\> $mydomain.MaxBadPasswordsAllowed = 0 

 # set lockout duration value (in seconds)
 PS C:\> $mydomain.AutoUnlockInterval = 1000
```

3. Turn on/enabled windows update service to start/auto on window startup

..

Edit 1: I posted some code before, now I have added other snippets as requested, I am still working on figuring out the auto start of windows updates. The challenge seems to be that - there are many options to do the same thing in Powershell. There seems to be an incredible amount of power, and the danger of messing up your system. So, I am looking for help in consolidating so I can add and maint the scripts on my own.

Answer (score 1):

PS is a scripting language - which means it is interpreted, like Python, Ruby, Perl, and, yes, CMD.EXE .BAT files. However there is a huge difference between the capabilities of the two.

Regarding lint, there is the `set-strictmode` command to diagnose some errors that wouldn't otherwise be called out. However, a scripting language is significantly different from a language like C (to which lint is applicable). Some of the dangerous things you could do in C, that lint would diagnose, just can't be done in a scripting language.

As far as your 3 items, SO is meant to help folks get help with coding. But you don't have much code posted, and it isn't clear if the code you do have works or if you're having trouble with it.

To get started I suggest googling for the three tasks (or last two if the line of code you have works), but add the word Powershell to your search.

You may also want to look at some tutorials on basic PS script. You could learn basic scripting in an hour or less of searching and reading.